# MUI-DataTables, How to customize filter dropdown select with extra column containing icon

Tags: filter, dropdown, multiple-columns, multi-select, mui-datatable

I am using MUI-DataTables (gregnb) and want to customize a multi-select dropdown in the filter tab, by adding an extra column to the dropdown.
Is it possible?  Would it be in filteroptions.display? or customFilterListOptions (which I use to customize the text in the chip) and if so how please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by: specifying filterType = 'custom' and returning Material-ui markup. i.e.

```
filterType = 'custom';
filterOptions = {
    names: getMyArray(),
    logic: (value, filters) => { ......
    },
     display: (filterList, onChange, index, column) => {
        return (
           <FormControl>
              <InputLabel htmlFor="select-multiple-chip">Location</InputLabel>
                  <Select
                      className ={class1.A}
                      multiple
                      value={filterList[index]}
                      renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
                      onChange={(event) => {
                      filterList[index] = event.target.value;
                      onChange(filterList[index], index, column);
                  }}
                  >                                                     

                  {locArr.map((name, name2) =>(
                      <MenuItem key={id} value={name}  className ={classesF.A}>
                          <Checkbox className ={classesF.D} />
                          <ListItemText primary={name}/>
                          <ListItemText primary={name2}/>
                     </MenuItem>
                 ))}
            </Select>
       </FormControl>
   );
```

}