# Can I store these selected filters in a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

Is it possible to store these selected filters in a variable and have it updated as well when the use selects another set of filters? If so, how?

[image]

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/muidatatables-custom-toolbar-forked-lrbf16

Comment: This answer contains an implementation that might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65415179/mui-datatables-filter-from-outside
If that doesn't work maybe you can take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69099064/mui-datatables-how-to-customize-filter-dropdown-select-with-extra-column-contai

Basically, you need to bypass the MUI implementation. So either of these 2 ways should help you. There is a `components` prop on the table too, that might be worth exploring in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that, you can use `onFilterChange` callback, like this :

```
const options = {
...

    onFilterChange: (column, filterList, type) => {
            const selectedFilters = this.extractFilters(filterList);
            console.log(selectedFilters);
          }
}
```

This function will be called everytime filter list changes.

Then, you declare function `extractFilters` which will extract all selected filters from passed `filterList` and it will return array object containting all selected filters :

```
 extractFilters = (filterList) => {
        let selectedFilters = [];
        filterList.forEach((filter) => {
          if (filter.length > 0) {
            selectedFilters.push(...filter);
          }
        });
        return selectedFilters;
      };
```

You can store this array in state.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/muidatatables-custom-toolbar-forked-ldz63t?file=/index.js) is working example.